# Graphviz for Matlab : Deleting nodes which have no edges

Tags: matlab, graphviz

I am using Graphviz for matlab.Is there a way to delete nodes which have no edges in the final graph, since my graph is very big( ~9100 nodes) and any other help on representing the graph in a better way would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you generate the graph? From code? If so, please post some of it.

Comment: I used the graphviz function which i found online...As input, I provided a binary matrix using which the function generates a graph.

Comment: The code part of the function is pretty large....https://code.google.com/p/graphviz4matlab/downloads/list

Comment: Is this homework? If so you should probably look at this: [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) or simply search for the term 'adjacency matrix'.

Comment: This is not HOMEWORK...I am relatively new to matlab and not very good at programming..The matrix which i provide for input is an adjacency matrix of the order 9057*9057..Based on which positions have the value '1' in the matrix, graphviz function creates an edge between the respective indices of the matrix..

Answer (score 1):

The input to `graphviz` is an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix), so you can do the following:

```
% Generate random adjacency matrix with no nodes connected to themselves
N = 10; 
adj = (randi(N, N) > 5) .* (ones(N) - eye(N));

% Spuriously set one row and column to zero: no connections for this node
adj(:, 2) = 0; adj(2, :) = 0;

% Find the nodes with no edges
noEdgeNodes = all(adj == 0, 1) & all(adj == 0, 2)'

noEdgeNodes =

 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

% Remove nodes with no edges
adj(noEdgeNodes, :) = []; 
adj(:, noEdgeNodes) = [];

% Call graphviz
graphViz4Matlab('-adjMat', adj, '-nodeLabels', ...
    arrayfun(@(x){num2str(x)}, 1:size(adj, 1)))
```